# Is gcp removed terminated vm logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, spot-instances

Is GCP Vm logs are deleted after termination of vm?

I was running a GCE sopt vm with MIG(Managed Instance Group). My VM instance terminated. When i check logs
of terminated Vm. I am not able to see logs of it.

Comment: Logs are kept 30 days by default. If you didn't change this config, you should find the logs in CLoud Logging.

Comment: +1 to @guillaumeblaquiere, to help you locate the VM run this query:
protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.instances.delete" AND resource.type="gce_instance"

Locate the resource.labels.instance_id and query that ID you should be able to see the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check Audit log retention periods in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods).

In my case I was still able to see the terminated spot VM logs in logging for the last 60 days.

You can use the query below to view the logs of the terminated spot VM instance.

Replace the PROJECT_ID with your project id:

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event
```

Then find the log entries with a similar line or statement below:

> system@google.com Instance was preempted.

You can read this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#:%7E:text=System%20Event%20audit%20logs%20contain,configure%2C%20exclude%2C%20or%20disable%20them.) for more information about "System Event audit logs"